# TypeScript: type of class that implements a certain interface or method

Tags: javascript, typescript

## Goal

I wanna have a type that describes an object with values of type: `Array<ClassRef>` where `ClassRef` is any class that must implement a certain interface.

## Approach

```js
type KeyClassMap<SomeUnionType> = {
   [key in keyof SomeUnionType]: Array<ClassRef>
} 

type ClassRef = new (...args: any[]) => any // should extend that interface

interface I {
   [Symbol.hasInstance](hint: string): boolean
}

const _map: KeyClassMap<UnionType> = {
   myKey: [Date, MyOwnClass, MyOtherClass] // <- all these should have implemented Symbol.hasInstance to check with `instanceof` operator
}
```

## Question

The example misses a declaration of a class that implements that interface. I am not sure how to do that.

Each class should only implement this one method (`[Symbol.hasInstance]`) to check if a value is an instance of that class.

I would like to know how to declare a type of a class that implements that interface or any other way to describe a class that has this method.

I assume that this is not really possible, so I appreciate any other tips.

Comment: Is it possible that `_map` should be of type `KeyClassMap<Whatever>`? If not I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: oh yeah sure, thanks @Grochni !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining your `ClassRef` type you are really specifying the type of its constructor function. As the constructor function returns an instance of the class you can force the class to implement a specific interface by forcing the return value of its constructor to implement that interface. Your code should look like this:

```
type ClassRef<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type KeyClassMap<SomeUnionType> = {
   [key in keyof SomeUnionType]: Array<ClassRef<I>>
}
```

If you want to use the `KeyClassMap` type in other places as well, you can of course add another generic to it instead of statically using the `I` interface.